# Query script not run in suggest box

Tags: suggestbox, google-app-maker

In AppMaker, one my datasources has a simple query script associated with, because I need a filter **everytime** the datasource is requested. I'm talking about a normal SQL based datasource (not calculated).

Is it normal than this query script is not used when the datasource is used in a Suggest box ? Because it breaks my app (the user is able via the suggest box to select items he's not even supposed to see).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The options for a suggest field text box can either be provided explicitly, by binding to the options property, or by specifying a database query on a model using a **startsWith** filter on a field. You can set the model and field for the latter option below.

So you can try to create calculated model with server script starts with

```
var name = query.filters.name.startsWith;
```

name is field of model

Comment: I'm using the "Suggest Box Query Options" to set up my box (because there is paging on this datasource). And if I use a calculated model, that will break the relation between this datasource and the main one (basically the suggest box is used to link an object of type B to an object of type A, being created)

Comment: "Suggest Box Query Options"  works on model directly, it doesn't touch any datasources. 
Options is list of stringd (List<String>), but it depends on datasource.
Hack: on "onValueChange" event, find "id" by string and set relation.
I don't like this idea, but it may works to you.